# monacaにおいて、特定の条件でiosのデバッグビルドを実行するとエラーになってしまう。

Tags: ios, monaca

monacaクラウドIDEにて、Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin(https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)
をcordovaプラグインに登録してiosビルドを通そうとするとエラーが出てしまいます。

これを削除すると、ビルドが通ります。
androidでも同条件でビルドエラーになってしまっていたのですが、androidのAndroidManifest.xmlをプラグイン内のAndroidManifest.xmlに上書きするとビルドが通るようになりました。
iosではplistファイルの上書きでは解決しませんでした。

こちらエラー分の一部になります。:

```
/Applications/Xcode6_4/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6_4/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -iquote /tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/Build/Intermediates/MonacaApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MonacaApp.build/MonacaApp-generated-files.hmap -I/tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/Build/Intermediates/MonacaApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MonacaApp.build/MonacaApp-own-target-headers.hmap -I/tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/Build/Intermediates/MonacaApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MonacaApp.build/MonacaApp-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/Build/Intermediates/MonacaApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MonacaApp.build/MonacaApp-project-headers.hmap -I/tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/usr/local/lib/include -I/tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/Build/Intermediates/UninstalledProducts/include -I/tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -I/tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/Build/Intermediates/MonacaApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MonacaApp.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/Build/Intermediates/MonacaApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MonacaApp.build/DerivedSources -F/tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -FMonacaApp/Plugins/phonegap-facebook-plugin -include /tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/MonacaApp-Prefix-edgvfsuxtpvleicazynggdrepcxi/MonacaApp-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/Build/Intermediates/MonacaApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MonacaApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FacebookConnectPlugin.d --serialize-diagnostics /tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/Build/Intermediates/MonacaApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MonacaApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FacebookConnectPlugin.dia -c /tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/MonacaApp/Plugins/phonegap-facebook-plugin/FacebookConnectPlugin.m -o /tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/Build/Intermediates/MonacaApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MonacaApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FacebookConnectPlugin.o
In file included from /tmp/monaca/57835e5a7e2193375f084608/ios/skeleton/platforms/ios/MonacaApp/Plugins/phonegap-facebook-plugin/FacebookConnectPlugin.m:11:
MonacaApp/Plugins/phonegap-facebook-plugin/FacebookConnectPlugin.h:11:9: fatal error: &apos;FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h&apos; file not found
#import &lt;FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h&gt;
    ^
1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
CompileC Build/Intermediates/MonacaApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MonacaApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FacebookConnectPlugin.o MonacaApp/Plugins/phonegap-facebook-plugin/FacebookConnectPlugin.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error executing command: xcodebuild

Unable to delete certificate matching &quot;&quot;

Build error: Error building project source code
```

証明書の不適合とのエラーかと思い、年のために一度iosのアプリ設定からやり直してみましたが、改善しませんでした。

同じエラーに遭遇された方、解決をされた方がいらっしゃればその方法を教授いただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

このプラグインは、内部でシンボリックリンクを使用しているため、Monacaに組み込むとビルドエラーになってしまいます。シンボリックリンクを実体ファイルに置き換えれば、ビルドが成功するようになります。

例えば、Macであれば次のようにします。
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin
からDownload ZIPで、phonegap-facebook-plugin-master.zip をダウンロードします。これを適当な作業ディレクトリに置いて、以下のコマンドを実行してゆきます

```
$ unzip phonegap-facebook-plugin-master.zip 
$ cd phonegap-facebook-plugin-master/platforms/ios/FacebookSDK.framework/
$ rm FacebookSDK 
$ rm Headers
$ rm Resources
$ rm Versions/Current
$ mv Versions/A/FacebookSDK .
$ mv Versions/A/Headers/ .
$ mv Versions/A/Resources/ .
$ cd ../../../..
$ zip -r phonegap-facebook-plugin-custom.zip phonegap-facebook-plugin-master -x phonegap-facebook-plugin-master/.git*
```

最後のzipコマンドにより、新しく「phonegap-facebook-plugin-custom.zip」ファイルが出来ているはずなので、これをMonaca IDEからプラグインとしてアップロードします。
プラグインの設定(APP_IDやAPP_NAME）などをIDE上で再設定します。

これで、再度ビルドすれば成功するとおもいます。

Comment: ばっちりビルドが通るようになりました。回答いただき感謝です。    
今度はandroidのビルドが通らなくなってしまいましたが。。。